# How can I delete a specific text from a file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm currently writing a bash script, I wan't this bash script to ask users a specific text, and if this text is exists on the file, the script will delete that text.

Code;

```bash
if [ ! -d /home/fixscript/AudioBot ]
then
echo -e "AudioBot yüklü değil!"
sleep 0.5
echo -e "Ana menüye yönlendiriliyorsunuz..."
else
echo -e "Hangi ID silinsin?"

read Cevap50
// if $Cevap50 exists in $file, then delete it.
fi
```

File;

```
//This is a config file
groupid = [ 625, 823, 824, 618 ] //If the user answer is 824, the script will only delete "824," from the file.
useruid = []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method would be:

```
sed "s/$Cevap50//g" <infile >outfile
```

This will produce a new file `outfile` being a copy of `infile` with any occurrence of the text contained in the variable `Cevap50` deleted.

In general, the text to be deleted is here interpreted as a **[regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)**, so you should avoid the following characters in this text: `^` `.` `[` `]` `$` `(` `)` `\` `*` `+` `{` `}` `?` as they have special meaning in a regular expression. You should also not use `/`, because - as you see - it is used as a delimiter in the command. If you will use digits or letters only, then no problem.

However note that in your case if the user answers `824`, then the script will delete **literally only** `824` from the file, so the output file will contain the following:

```
groupid = [ 625, 823, , 618 ] //If the user answer is , the script will only delete "," from the file.
```

To delete `824` **and** the following comma, the user has to answer `824,`.

This can be of course modified to delete contents of `Cevap50` **plus optionally** the following comma, by making use of the regular expression features. The command needs to be changed it to:

```
sed -r "s/${Cevap50},?//g" <infile >outfile
```

Comment: It worked but I have one other problem.. As I said, there is an line called `useruid = []` in my question. the userid will be filled like this; `userid = [ "YoTK81eXy9w5KO+BLgrr2+yTUYA=" ]` But It seems It isn't working with this code, `sed -r "s@\"${Cevap50}\"@@" <rights.toml.eski >rights.toml`. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the contents of the variable `Cevap50` in the above example? Your `userid` contains a `+` character, which has special meaning in a regular expression, so it must be quoted within the variable. Which means than when inputting the value, user must write `\+` instead of just `+`.

Comment: But I can't make the users write \+, is there any other methods?

Comment: @Eyup You can replace `+` with `\+` after reading input with the following command: `Cevap50=${Cevap50//+/\\+}`

Comment: I will try and tell you the results, thanks!

Comment: I tried and it worked, Thanks! But now I have problem with `/` character.

Comment: If you insist to do it in bash, it is best to stick to letters and numbers and avoid using special characters as each one of them will require special treatment and escaping. If you want to work on arbitrary text, use another scripting language that is better suited for text processing, for example Perl.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your offer. But like I said I need to do it in bash because I don't know any other scripting language. The comment that you gave me `"Cevap50=${Cevap50//+/\\+}"` was perfectly fine. I just need something like that but it should include `/` character too. Because I'm working with Base64.

Comment: If you want to use `/` in your text, you must use another delimiter in `sed` command. Try to use for example `sed -r "s#${Cevap50},?##g"` instead of `sed -r "s/${Cevap50},?//g"`. It should work with `/`.

Comment: Will It work with `+` character too? If yes, so can I delete `Cevap50=${Cevap50//+/\\+}` this line too right?

Comment: No, you can't delete that line. The issue with `+` and `/` character is different, so both are needed. You should learn about regular expression syntax and the syntax of `sed` commands, then you will know in details how it works.